# Equation for finding vertices of a rectangular prism after rotations

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, rotation

I am trying to find an equation that will help me find the vertices of a rectangular prism after it has been rotated about its center point in the `x,y, and z` dimensions.

For example, I am given a rectangular prism with side `lengths: l = 10, w =4, h = 1 (l corresponding to x axis, w to y axis, and h to z axis )`. I also know that the prism has been `rotated30 degrees about the x axis`, `45 degrees about the y axis`, and `20 degrees about the z axis.` If my center `point is (1,3,5)`, I would like to find an equation to determine where each of my vertices will end up after the prism has been rotated fully.

I have found many sources that can give me an answer in `2 dimensions` but I have yet to see a source that helps me find this equation in all `3 dimensions` I am looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (I don't necessarily need the answer to the example given above, just an equation for how to solve it would help me out tremendously! )

Comment: Maybe you can look into this - https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/programming-3d-shapes/a/rotating-3d-shapes

Comment: I looked into this already and it seems this source is only useful if I already know all the vertices of my prism which I do not.

Answer (score 2):

Given the center point and side lengths, all vertices of a rectangular prism can be calculated as follows:

```
center: (x,y,z)
v = (x±l/2,y±w/2,z±h/2)
```

Using all possible combinations of pluses and minuses, we get all the vertices. Then, translate the rectangular prism to the center: `v = v - center`. Then, rotate the translated vertices about each axis:

Rotation about x-axis:

```
v.y = v.y*cos(theta) - v.z*sin(theta)
v.z = v.z*cos(theta) + v.y*sin(theta)
```

Rotation about y-axis:

```
v.x = v.x*cos(theta) + v.z*sin(theta)
v.z = v.z*cos(theta) - v.x*sin(theta)
```

Rotation about z-axis:

```
v.x = v.x*cos(theta) - v.y*sin(theta)
v.y = v.y*cos(theta) + v.x*sin(theta)
```

(Equations from [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/programming-3d-shapes/a/rotating-3d-shapes) khan academy article mentioned in above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69125805/equation-for-finding-vertices-of-a-rectangular-prism-after-rotations#comment122173825_69125805))

Finally, translate the vertices back (`v = v + center`)